# Cocoapods: LoadError - no such file to load

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoapods, podfile

I am trying to add a pod to my Xcode project. I am getting this error:

> LoadError - no such file to load -- xcodeproj/prebuilt/universal-darwin13.0-1.8.7/xcodeproj_ext
> /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require' /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in` require'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.0/lib/xcodeproj/ext.rb:6
> /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `gem_original_require' /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in` require'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/xcodeproj-0.14.0/lib/xcodeproj/project.rb:4
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:488:in `compute_target_platforms' /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:485:in` each'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:485:in `compute_target_platforms' /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:55:in` analyze'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:171:in `analyze' /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:94:in` resolve_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:52:in `section' /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:93:in` resolve_dependencies'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:86:in `install!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:38:in` run_install_with_update'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/command/project.rb:68:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/claide-0.3.2/lib/claide/command.rb:206:in` run'
> /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:51:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/cocoapods-0.27.1/bin/pod:19 /usr/bin/pod:23:in` load'
> /usr/bin/pod:23

My podfile contents:

```
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.21.0'
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: does it contain just that?

Comment: yes, tried by giving platform as well..but still it dint work.

Comment: has it ever worked before?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I also was seeing this. Running this fixed the issue:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods && pod install
```

Comment: for me it didn't fix the issue :( I just upgraded our build server to mavericks and now Jenkins shows this error when building and installing cocoapods again didn't fix it

Answer (score 4):

Finally found a solution: I'm running old Xcode4 and new Xcode5 in same machine with same projects. At some point **I seem to have lost command line tools** (and iPhone5 simulator).

Reinstalling command line tools solved the problem for me. Since Xcode 4.6.3 menu item **`Xcode - Preferences - Downloads - Components`** didn't have command-line tools any more for unknown reasons, here is another way to install them:

```
xcode-select --install

--install
          Opens a user interface dialog to request automatic installation of the
          command line developer tools.
```

Now running "pod install" worked just fine.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using 10.10 and are seeing this error (/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:) try this

```
Open Xcode 6 > Preferences > Locations
Command Line Tools version to Xcode 6.0
Uninstall cocoapods/xcodeproj then re-install.

sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj
sudo gem install xcodeproj
sudo gem install cocoapods

pod --version
```

Answer (score 0):

As follow, this my problem:
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0_2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require': cannot load such file -- Xcodeproj (LoadError)

from 
 /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.5.0_2/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'

from Script/ModuleDiscover.rb:9:in `'

Just attempt many method, and it is no use , finnaly I resolve the problem just bellow:

1、command + q,exit xcode

2、open terminal and "open -a xcode". all fine

Answer (score 0):

Files added in the pods but their reference is not considered until you run the command pod install. Just runt the bellow command:

`pod install`

Answer (score 0):

For the M1 mac, please install CocoaPods from Homebrew as installing CocoaPods from gem doesn't seem to work. Visit [brew.sh](https://brew.sh) for more information.

`brew install cocoapods`