# Error when I load 'pod install' in Mavericks

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5, osx-mavericks, cocoapods

When I load "pod install" in my project, is occurring this problems:

[image]

My podfile has this:

```
pod 'Reachability',
pod 'AFNetworking',
pod 'FMDB'
```

I found this question, but the answer not fix my problem: 
[Cocoapods No such file to load Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674550/cocoapods-no-such-file-to-load-error)

The errors is occurring after I updated to Mavericks.

Comment: You reinstalled cocoapods after the mavericks update? I think there was a change to the version of Ruby which may necessitate a reinstall of ruby gems