# Cocoapods cannot load such file LoadError

Tags: ios, ruby, xcode, macos, cocoapods

I recently upgraded to Xcode 6.2 and OSX 10.10 and now adding a pod to my project doesn't work. I get the following error:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- xcodeproj/prebuilt/universal.x86_64-darwin14-2.0.0/xcodeproj_ext (LoadError)

I've tried all the fixes listed in this related question for Ruby 1.8 ([Cocoapods No such file to load Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19674550/cocoapods-no-such-file-to-load-error)) and I'm still getting the same error.

I've also tried everything from this issue:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2219

Things I've tried:

```
sudo gem uninstall xcodeproj
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install xcodeproj
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

If I go to Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Command Line Tools: I only have an option for Xcode 6.2, so some places say to set this to Xcode 6.0, but I don't have this option.

Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten to add the following to the top of the podfile.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
```

In case someone else makes this oversight and comes across this page, hopefully this will be of help.